# How to load updated image from server using Picasso/Glide?

Tags: java, android, picasso, android-glide

I have more than 300 images in the app. I need to show three at a time in the screen. But loading the image every time from the server takes 1-2 secs sometimes. I want to cache the images but when image gets updated from the server the url remains same. How to use cache and automatically update image and cache it for further use?